# Target negated selectors using .on() for swipe events in jQM

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-selectors, event-handling, jquery

**Background:**

I am developing a navigation class for swipe events in [jquery-mobile](/questions/tagged/jquery-mobile). The class reads a tree-like sitemap from a JSON structure and assigns `swipeleft` and `swiperight` events to navigate through a top level nodes in the tree. It assigns `swipedown` and `swipeup` event handlers to children of each node, and `swipeleft` and `swiperight` handlers to siblings of those children and so on for infinite levels. I'm only attaching these handlers to the currently loaded page, identified by `$.mobile.activePage` and I'm using `$(document).one()` function to ensure these handlers are never bound twice. The class reads the pageMap structure during the `$(document).bind('pagebeforeshow')` hook.

Below is some *draft* sample code for handling swipeleft and swiperight in a single level of the tree:

```
/** @todo 
 *  tidy up the next 2 conditionals into a single function and a mapping object
 *  that can handle left, right, up and down
 */
//if this isn't the first page
if(page.prev !== undefined) {
    //attach the swipe handler to the previous page
    Utils.logger('log', 'Binding a swiperight to ' + page.id);
    $(page.id).one('swiperight', 'div.content', function(event) {
        Utils.logger('log', 'Navigating to previous slide: ' + page.prev.url); //debug
        $.mobile.changePage(            
            page.prev.url, {
                transition: 'slide',
                direction: 'reverse'
            }
        );
    });
    //debugging
    Utils.logger('log', 'Route: ' + page.prev.url + ' <== ' + page.url);
}

//if this isn't the last page
if(page.next !== undefined) {
    //attach the swipe handler to the previous page
    Utils.logger('log', 'Binding a swiperight to ' + page.id);
    $(page.id).one('swipeleft', 'div.content', function(event) {
        Utils.logger('log', 'Navigating to next slide: ' + page.next.url); //debug
        $.mobile.changePage(            
            page.next.url, {
                transition: 'slide'
            }
        );
    });
    //debugging
    Utils.logger('log', 'Route: ' + page.url + ' ==> ' + page.next.url);
}
```

*In case you're wondering, `Utils.logger` is just a simple wrapper class for `console`*

**The Problem:**

My problem is that the pages in this tree can contain many different types of elements. Some are simple and look much like a photo gallery slide show. I have no problems with those kind of pages. Other pages contain forms and nested slideshows. So there might be a DIV in my page which handles swipe events to create a slideshow inside of a slideshow - let's ignore that for now and focus on somethinge even more trivial: I have in my form things like slider controls. Sliding a slider on a touch screen is equivalent to swiping a touch screen... I think you know where this is going...! **If I slide my slider in the form, I trigger a swipe event which changes the page in my navigation system**... DOH!

**How can I ensure that my page navigation swipes only target my div.content, and ignores all the things mentioned above?** I've tried using the selectors parameter of .on(), but I think what I am looking for is a way to negate/not those selectors?

Here is an example of my markup (for this example it is stripped down to the essentials - but please imagine a large form with multiple fieldsets):

```
<div data-role="page" id="feedback" class="page">
    <div data-role="content" id="feedback-form" class="content">
        <form action="#" method="get">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="more-info">Would you like more info?</label>
                <select name="slider2" id="more-info" data-role="slider">
                    <option value="off">No</option>
                    <option value="on">Yes</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="slider">Please rate this presentation out of 10:</label>
                <input type="range" name="slider" id="slider" value="5" min="0" max="10" data-highlight="true"  />
            </div>
            <div class="ui-body ui-body-b">
                <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                        <div class="ui-block-a"><button type="reset" id="reset" data-theme="d" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="left">Cancel</button></div>
                        <div class="ui-block-b"><button type="submit" data-theme="b" data-icon="check" data-iconpos="right" >Submit</button></div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**So, to clarify and summarise:**
I'm looking for a way to target `div.content` with swipe events, but to ***ignore*** any swipe event that occurs on a child node of `<form>` (not the `<form>` itself) plus any swipe event on a collection of divs which have their own swipe events - all of which I can add easily add a class to like: `.ignorePageSwipe`. Oh, and of course it should not be a performance hog!!!